# Растянуть TextField по высоте в List

Tags: java, jasperreports

[image: Шаблон отчета]
Отчет в области `detail`состоит из текстового поля (2) и списка с полями (3, 4, 5, 6). При переполнении поля 2 соответственно поля списка то же должны растянуться, но получается как на картинке ниже:
[image: Часть сформированного отчета]
Как сделать что бы поля в списке то же растягивались по высоте?

Полный отчет:
[image: Сформированный отчет]

```
mvn compile
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="local.vssp.Main"
```

[минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример на github](https://github.com/TinoAjato/jsr-mcve-test)

Comment: @Bald колонка 7 входит в область detail, а не элемента List(

Comment: а где эти JAR'ники? их не так лехко найти

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov какие именно? В pom-е половина из них вообще не нужна, как понимаю - это скопировал из реального проекта, но пока не разбирался как определить нужны они или нет.

Comment: В общем ни со списком, ни с таблицей, ни с подотчетом у меня ничего не вышло. Вероятно это не возможно вообще.

Comment: `SmetaTimesNewRoman`, `jasperreports-metadata:6.6.0`, `jasperreports-fonts:6.7.0`, `itext:2.1.7.js6` я просто хотел запустить, а в Мавене половины из этого нет.

Comment: > `Вероятно это не возможно вообще` - возможно, я не очень знаком с этой библиотекой, просто хотелось пощупать))

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov 'SmetaTimesNewRoman' - это TimesNewRoman для русского языка)  и остальные jar-ники для работы этого куска не нужны, можно убить.

Comment: `SmetaTimesNewRoman` хорошо, но где его брать? Он совсем не гуглится)). и еще, смотрите в мавене ведь вроде все библиотеке 6.8, а у вас 6.6, не лучше ли 6.8 использовать, или не запуститься?

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov вероятно запустится, не знаю. SmetaTNR сделал по этому - https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-render-cyrillic-symbols-pdf-and-jrxml-report-jasperreports-library-custom-java-application

Answer (score 0):

Для текстовых полей установить `Stretch Type` в значение `Relative to Band Height`

Comment: Устанавливал. Не помогает(